# CSV Helper: Parsing null vs empty cells

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper to parse the CSV file.

I am having some issues to identify when a null cell value or a cell with some value (ie one or more spaces).

Issue is when the user add just one space in the file in its cell and uploads the file, the CSV helper trims that cell value so that value is passed as "".

Now when the user doesnt add anything(or types) to the cell this is also passed as like "".

So what I want is:
- Nulls should not be allowed to be uploaded.
- One or more spaces in a cell is allowed.

How can I achieve this using CSVHelper. Below is my sample code:

```
using (TextReader fileReader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
{
    var configuration = new Configuration
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = parameter.HasHeader,
        Delimiter = parameter.Delimiter.ToString(),
        Quote = parameter.Quote
    };
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader, configuration))
    {
        for (int rowIndex = 0; await csv.ReadAsync(); rowIndex++)
        {
            var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>() as IDictionary<string, object>;
            string[] row = record?.Select(i => i.Value as string).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {

               //process rows              

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the csv example:

```
"1"," ","1"
"2","0"," "
"3","","1"
```

In the above csv first row has second column with one space which should be allowed
Third row has 2nd column with null which should not be allowed.

Anything in my code which is missing or any workaround to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the TrimOptions?  I can't remember what the default value is (so perhaps this will no make a difference), but try:  "TrimOptions = None" inside of your configuration block.

Comment: Thanks just tried that but doest work. It still trimming cell values.

Comment: ANother strange thing thats happening is if the file has 2 or more rows and the first row has one column witht the space and second row and one column with space, If I debug throw I can see only the first row column has a space, for all other rows I can see the space has been trimmed. But when I see the csv file in the notepad I can see each value has a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CsvHelper 15.0.3

With the following code I show spaces where there are spaces and empty where it is empty.

Maybe there is something else going on?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessRecords();            
}

static async void ProcessRecords()
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader("\"1\",\" \",\"1\"\n\"2\",\"0\",\" \"\n\"3\",\"\",\"1\""))
    {
        var configuration = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = false,
            Delimiter = ",",
            Quote = '"'
        };
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration))
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; await csv.ReadAsync(); rowIndex++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Row: {rowIndex}");
                var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                string[] row = record?.Select(i => i.Value as string).ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (row[i] == " ")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Has a space");
                    }
                    if (row[i] == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Empty value");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was we were using a little older version 12 of csvhelper. And when I saw your post where you have mentioned the version I first updated the version and it seems to fix the issue. Maybe this issue was fixed in the newer versions. Thanks for your inputs.